# Jenkins Hangs forever

Tags: jenkins

I have created a job in jenkins to checkout one of the project from CVS.

It shows the progress bar and running forever, never comes to halt, this is the message that I see in the log:

```
Started by user anonymous [workspace] $ cvs -Q -z3 -d :sserver:<username>:<passwd>@str2-dev-cvsbug:/cvsrepo co -P -D "Tuesday, September 6, 2011 3:02:43 PM UTC" core-module
```

I just renamed the username, passwd and cvsrepo, module name.

In the windows explorer, I see that module is checked out as I see the latest time stamp on all the folders.

Environment:

```
Jenkins 1.410
Tortoise CVS 1.9.8
JBoss AS 5.1
```

Comment: When you run this from commandline instead, what is the result?  I have a feeling it is hanging because it is waiting for some sort of user response.

Comment: @adam.kuyrkendall : thank you for your reply. I tried in the command line it hangs in there too with the above command. But I have removed -Q -Z3 -D and complete date string and tried " {cvs -d :sserver:<username>:<passwd>@str2-dev-cvsbug:/repo co -P module1 module2} , it worked in the command line. Not sure what does it mean by -Q -Z3 and the purpose of these attributes in Jenkins and CVS.

Answer (score 8):

Have you tried to rename the Jenkins job? Somehow that worked for me...

Comment: It might be because jenkins will create a new directory in your workspace. But it didn't work for me.