# Strange build status for Jenkins/Maven submodule

Tags: maven, hudson, jenkins, maven-3

I have a Jenkins maven-3 project with many submodules.  The status of the main project is shown in the right side of the image below.  On the left side is one submodule.  I don't understand why Jenkins believes the submodule is still being built about 11 times (all the blinking status lights).  Does anyone know why this happens?

[image: Jenkins status for module and project]

UPDATED: After restarting both slaves and the master node, the blinking builds stopped blinking.  However, the build statuses of the Jenkins project (right side in picture above) is now shown as all red!  How can a reboot of Jenkins switch a project from unstable to broken?  Proof:

[image: new jenkins status for project]

UPDATE #2: It turns out that the submodule was failing to build due to an OutOfMemoryError:

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread
    at java.lang.Thread.start0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Thread.start(Thread.java:574)
    at java.lang.Shutdown.runHooks(Shutdown.java:128)
    at java.lang.Shutdown.sequence(Shutdown.java:173)
    at java.lang.Shutdown.exit(Shutdown.java:218)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exit(Runtime.java:90)
    at java.lang.System.exit(System.java:869)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.maven3.agent.Maven3Main.main(Maven3Main.java:149)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.maven3.agent.Maven3Main.main(Maven3Main.java:63)
Triggering a new build of foo-main-cobertura #345
Finished: SUCCESS
```

But note that final status: "SUCCESS".  Really?!  And it triggered a downstream project "foo-main-cobertura" which is only supposed to trigger on successful or unstable builds, not failed builds.  So the new question is, why does Jenkins interpret an OOM error as successful?

Answer (score 0):

You has infinitive loop (possible in one test). Try to reset [jenkins](/questions/tagged/jenkins) process and check again.

Comment: This module has no unit tests.  However, you may be on the right track as this module does have one or more custom maven plugins.  If one of those was badly behaved...

Comment: The similar problems: [Jenkins Hangs forever](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7322871/651140) [Build is hanging](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build+is+hanging) [JENKINS-4165](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-4165)

Comment: All executors were free.  There were no "actively hung" builds.  If it happens again, I'll get the thread dumps.

Comment: So here's another question: if the submodule still thinks it's building as in build 1969, then why does the parent project have a status of solid yellow (unstable)?  Shouldn't the parent build status icon also be blinking?

Comment: I do not know why your build hanging. I found explanation, that maybe you have remote resources still open (for example you deploy or publish to remote server and communication hanging). Try timeout plugin and set number of executors to 1.

Comment: Nothing was hung.  If you look at my 2nd update to the original post, the build was failing during that specific sub-module with an OOM error, but Jenkins interpreted this is "ok" for some weird reason.  I've submitted this to the Jenkins email list to get their input.  In my mind this is a serious problem with Jenkins or the Jenkins/Maven integration.

Comment: For now, I've gotten around the issue by switching to a 64-bit JVM.  I no longer get the OOM error and the build is truly successful instead of "wrongly successful" :)  However, there is still a Jenkins and/or Maven issue here.