# Jenkins Build Is Hanging

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, automated-tests, robotframework

We are using jenkins for the continuous integration.

But now, Build jobs are not getting executed after running for a few seconds, at the same time it's not at all showing any error messages also( Not getting any error messages in it's web console ). Seems like build process is hanging for a long time.

.

Here is the screenshot of the web console & jenkins log file ( /var/log/jenkins.log)
[image]

[image]

> I just went through the jenkins -> Manage jenkins -> manage nodes sections & did not find any disk space issues here : Currently there are 2 executors in master node.

[image]

Have you ever faced this kind of issue before ? What will be the reason for this problem ?  Is it due to any disk space / memory problems ?

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I found that the batch script I was kicking off from Jenkins was the problem.

I'm using Katalon Studio to run a suite of test cases and found that the `'-consoleLog'` flag was causing the job to hang. Once I'd removed the flag I could see the test case was able to print to the Jenkins console output.

Example with:

```
katalon -noSplash -runMode=console -consoleLog
-projectPath="%USERPROFILE%\repository\katalon-testing\test-project\test-project-one.prj" 
-retry=0 -testSuitePath="Test Suites/test-project/test-project-one" 
-executionProfile="uat" -browserType="Chrome"
```

Example without:

```
katalon -noSplash -runMode=console 
-projectPath="%USERPROFILE%\repository\katalon-testing\test-project\test-project-one.prj" 
-retry=0 -testSuitePath="Test Suites/test-project/test-project-one" 
-executionProfile="uat" -browserType="Chrome"
```

Before solving the issue, I was confused as my tests were passing on the server it was just that Jenkins wasn't able to see them passing so it would hang.

I assume that when Jenkins sees the output in the console it is able to stop the job as intended.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience one of the reasons why Jenkins build got stuck, is that you call from your job to another one and don't provide it with all of it's parameters, or one of you steps make it stuck.

My advice it go with the elimination strategy. Try to execute a simple test job, if it passed good we know that the problem is with your job. If not we probebly dealing with some infrastructure issue. If you got into conclusion that your problem is with your job try to run each step apart and try to figure what which one get you stuck. Then add some logging to it so you can point more accurately on the problem. When you get more details let me know, and I will try to assist as much as I can.

Comment: I have created this job to execute automation test scripts written in robot framework.This particular job will try to execute 10 test cases(I have verified each test scripts individually&working fine from terminal).This job is not at all invoking any other build jobs or not accepting any parameters from user !                                         Another thing, this same job was working fine till last week ..! It recently started this behavior. When I start this build job, it will execute either 3 or 4 test cases without any issue & will hang before executing the remaining scripts.

Comment: After running for a long time, it's not at all stopping by itself or not throwing any error messages. I have added the screenshot of jenkins log file. Saw one similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7322871/jenkins-hangs-forever) .. That answers too didn't work for me. Also found kind of similar documentation [here](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build+is+hanging) related to build hang issue.  Am using jenkins v. 1.625. Currently have 2 executers associated with master node.

Comment: Try to start the jenkins slave by Java web start and not as windows service.

Comment: Right now am **running jenkins as a service** .I have edited the configuration file ( /etc/sysconfig/jenkins ) &  **changed user as jenkins** ! So, If I not start jenkins as a service, ( that means I have to start jenkins as a different user ) I will lose all these current build jobs & associated datas created along with that.. ??

Comment: My bad, I thought you are using Jenkins slaves. It sounds like there is something wrong with your job, maybe it depends on other resources over the network which are no longer exists? Try to execute a simple job that just echo some output. If it works, try to execute this job manually and let us know if it passed.

Comment: Am sure that this build job is not at all accessing any resource file from network & not at all depends on any other build jobs. As I mentioned earlier, I have created this job to execute automation test script written in robot framework. This job will try to execute 10 automation test scripts & each of them are perfectly working fine when I tried to run through command line ! But right now, according to current status, if I start this particular build job, this will execute 2 or 3 test scripts (or sometimes not at starting ) & will hang the process after that! Willn't execute after that..

Comment: same happening with me - test cases, jenkins, build job, stuck, could not figure out why is it happening. This used to happen on local system on a different project also, while other systems were able to run same set of test cases. I wasn't able to infer at that time also what actually the issue was.